# Why @JMSListener stops listening events without any error or exception in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, spring-jms

I'm consuming events from Tibco EMS using `@JMSListener(destination = "myDestination", concurrency = "1-2")` and pushing them to Kafka.

Here's my `ConfigClass`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class ConfigClass {
     @Bean(name = "emsConFactory")
     public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {
          final TibjmsConnectionFactory factory = new TibjmsConnectionFactory();
    
          factory.setServerUrl(url);
          factory.setUserName(userName);
          factory.setUserPassword(password);
    
          return factory;
     }
    
     @Bean
     public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() throws JMSException {
          DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
          factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
          return factory;
     }
}
```

But the consumer is stopping without any exception or error.

Logs after consuming last msg:

```
2022-07-20 17:24:42.215 DEBUG 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending PRODUCE request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=PRODUCE, apiVersion=7, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=1274507) and timeout 30000 to node 2: {acks=-1,timeout=30000,partitionSizes=[jms-json-horeca-ims-feed-1=419]}
2022-07-20 17:24:42.217 DEBUG 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received PRODUCE response from node 2 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=PRODUCE, apiVersion=7, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=1274507): ProduceResponseData(responses=[TopicProduceResponse(name='jms-json-horeca-ims-feed', partitionResponses=[PartitionProduceResponse(index=1, errorCode=0, baseOffset=3236704, logAppendTimeMs=-1, logStartOffset=2214655, recordErrors=[], errorMessage=null)])], throttleTimeMs=0)
2022-07-20 17:24:42.217 DEBUG 1 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] ProducerId: 8365; Set last ack'd sequence number for topic-partition jms-json-horeca-ims-feed-1 to 248953
2022-07-20 17:24:46.551 DEBUG 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-3] o.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch  : Counting down[http-nio-80-exec-3] latch=2
2022-07-20 17:24:46.551 DEBUG 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-3] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Calling [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint@750d3d61].closeSocket([org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@b14cd7f:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@686840e4:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/100.105.73.169:80 remote=/100.107.212.96:42696]])
2022-07-20 17:24:48.538 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-80-Acceptor] o.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch  : Counting up[http-nio-80-Acceptor] latch=2
2022-07-20 17:24:48.538 DEBUG 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Before fill(): parsingHeader: [true], parsingRequestLine: [true], parsingRequestLinePhase: [0], parsingRequestLineStart: [0], byteBuffer.position(): [0], byteBuffer.limit(): [0], end: [113]
2022-07-20 17:24:48.538 DEBUG 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@43d1784a:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@686840e4:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/100.105.73.169:80 remote=/10.0.79.46:39190]], Read from buffer: [0]
```

Thread dump:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1otTaK458itGmvDzgqVpCgE2MEfs9hMt-WFJ2F2Rllk0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How do you know the consumer is stopping? Have you taken any thread dumps from the consumer application? If so, can you paste one into the question?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have not taken thread dump. I'm consuming from the queue and if the consumer is stopped the lag in queue get increased. It gets normal once I restart the pod

Comment: You need to get some thread dumps to see what the consuming application is actually doing when it stalls. It may be hung in another call (e.g. sending the message to Kafka).

Comment: Any feedback here?

Comment: waiting for @JmsListener stop consuming messages so that I can take thread dump

Comment: org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Calling [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint@750d3d61].closeSocket([org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@b14cd7f:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@686840e4:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/100.105.73.169:80 remote=/100.107.212.96:42696]])

getting this log

Comment: That appears unrelated to the consumer issue at this point.

Comment: One more observation, I have 2 pods and they both stopped with the interval of 2 sec and same logs

Comment: If they're both using the same shared resource (e.g. Kafka instance) that would make sense. Did you ever get those thread dumps? If so, please add them to the question.

Comment: is there any alternatige for @JmsListener for consuming records?
yes I'm using shared resource. Now I dont have thread dump will get it next time when listener stops

Comment: Yes, there are alternatives to Spring's JmsListener. The simplest is just using the JMS API directly. However, changing your application at this point would be premature since you don't have a clear understanding of root cause of the problem.

Comment: @JustinBertram added thread dump
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1otTaK458itGmvDzgqVpCgE2MEfs9hMt-WFJ2F2Rllk0/edit

Comment: @JustinBertram did you find something?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after discussing with network and devops team and checking the logs from server side we found out that this was caused by firewall due to which network was getting dropped